# pass array byte to getReader

Tags: java, http

How can I pass array byte to getReader without changes data.

```
byte_msg = Some array byte
println(">>>" + byte_msg)
HttpServletRequest.getReader returns new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byte_msg)))
```

And post reciever:

```
byte_msg = IOUtils.toByteArray(post.request.getReader)
println("<<<" + byte_msg)
```

And print return. Why do I get different answers?

```
>>>[B@38ffd135
<<<[B@60c0c8b5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out the result of `byte[].toString()` - which *isn't* the value of the byte array... it's just the value returned by `Object.toString()` - `[B` for "byte array", `@` and then the hash code. You need to convert the data to hex or something like that - which you need to do explicitly. For example, you could use the [`Hex`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encodeHex%28byte%5B%5D%29) class from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/):

```
String hex = new String(Hex.encode(byte_msg));
```

Not that if this is arbitrary binary data you should *not* use `InputStreamReader` to convert it to a string in the first place. `InputStreamReader` is designed for binary data which is encoded text data - and IMO you should specify the encoding, too.

If you want to transfer arbitrary binary data, you should *either* transfer it without any conversion into text (so see whether your post class allows that) *or* use something like hex or base64 to convert to/from binary data *safely*.

Answer (score 0):

`IOUtils.toByteArray` creates a new `ByteArrayOutputStream` then uses `toByteArray()` which creates a new `byte[]` and this array being a new objects has a new object id (the hash code you see, which is different). And this happens even if the content of the array was not changed.

In this case the mere observation (via `IOUtils.toByteArray`) has altered the output, because this check creates a new `byte[]` ;)

As Jon said, check the content of the array to see if there are any changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the content arrays you can convert the content of array to string using :

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(byte[])
```

and then print the result to stdout.

```
println(">>>" + Arrays.toString(byte_msg));
```

[j.u.Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5b%5d%29) documentation is here.